# Pycharm doesn't recognize Django installation

Tags: python, django, macos, pycharm

I'm trying to create a new django project in Pycharm and I'm getting an error "No Django Support Installed in Selected Interpreter". After getting the message the first time I installed django, but the message persists. I have three versions of python installed: 2.5, 2.6 and 2.7, and I get the same message with all three. I can use the django commands from the terminal so it's definitely installed. I'm using Mac Os X 10.9.

Any pointers?

Thanks

Comment: are you using any virtual envs?

Comment: I'm using Mac Os X 10.9 too, installed fresh python from macports (brew analogue), then pip, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper, then updated `.profile`

Comment: Did you select python from venv with installed Django in PyCharm "Project Interpreter" options?(also Django should be listed in this section as installed package)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks guys, just tried again and got an "install django" option which fixed it. Don't know why that showed up now but not before.

Answer (score 0):

go to file/setting/Project:"name project"
there you should add your interpreter that you want use for your project